# deliver results of two years of data in one query

Tags: sql-server

I am needing some help with a query that will provide the results of two years of data on one output. For example, in just comparing units;

**Query**:

```
select 
year 1,count(*),
year 2, count(*)
From db
WHERE year1 >= DATEADD(yy,-1,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()),0)) 
AND year1 <= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 12, 0)
AND
year2 >= DATEADD(yy,0,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()),0))
AND year2 <= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) , 0)
```

**Visual of results**:

```
2016 Units  2017 units
   3000        1200
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: I don't quite understanding what you are asking. Would you so kindly show a small data sample of your table(s)? Since you already presented us with a desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use case when statement + sum aggregat, assuming `yy` is your date columns :

```
select
    sum(case when '2016' = Year(yy) then 1 else 0 end) as "2016 units",
    sum(case when '2017' = Year(yy) then 1 else 0 end) as "2017 units"
From table
```

will produce a single row :

```
2016 Units  2017 units
   3000        1200
```

another presentation (multi row):

```
select
    Year(yy) as year,
    count as units
From table
where Year(yy) in (2016,2017)
group by
    Year(yy)
```

will produce :

```
year Units
2016 3000
2017 1200
```